# -'s suffix for things?

Tags: word-usage

According to Oxford Learner's Dictonaries, the ***-'s* suffix** can have these two meanings:

*(added to nouns)*

**1** belonging to

> *the woman's hat*
>
> *Peter's desk*
>
> *children's clothes*

**2** used to refer to somebody's home or, in British English, a particular shop

> *Shall we go to David's (= David's house) tonight?*
>
> *(British English) I'll call in at the chemist's on my way home*

So except for the last example, it looks like it's always used for people but not for things.

Is it really like that?

**Song lyrics or Song's lyrics?**

Comment: It’s a _general rule of thumb_ that the Saxon genitive (_X’s Y_) is more likely to occur with nouns that rank higher on the [animacy scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animacy), while the Norman genitive (_Y of X_) is more likely to occur with nouns that rank lower on it. But it’s not neat or straight-cut, and there are many overlaps and exceptions in either direction.

Comment: Especially given the tendency to use body parts metaphorically. We talk about _Bill's head, leg,_ or _foot_, but _the head, leg,_ or _foot of a table_.

Comment: It's also becoming more acceptable to drop the apostrophe for attributive rather than true possessive usages. This leads to such wonderful possibilities as _We bought much of the children's clothing from the childrens clothing department at Horrid's this year_.